# How to export uml diagram in other extension?

Tags: phpstorm

When I click the save icon a box appear to select the folder but I can save the uml diagram only in `.uml` extension. My goal is save the uml diagram in other extension like `.png` or other. Someone could help  me to achieve this?

Comment: Your question is not about the file name extension which is just a few characters, but about the actual type of the content, be it `uml` or an image which is something totally different. You will have to use a separate utility for the conversion, one that is specialized on `uml` handling. `dia` might be a good candidate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dia_(software)

Comment: @arkascha uhm so I guess I can't export the diagram in other extension?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, no.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Hope for this feature in future.

Comment: I just see that you can directly print diagrams. That means you can output `PDF` documents into a file by using a pseudo printer. `PDF` documents are very close to an image and can be converted easily if really required.

Comment: yes, infact. Thanks for this :)

Comment: If you are using some intelligent printing system like `CUPS` or similar you can even automate that and define an advanced pseudo printer for this which outputs some graphics format directly, since you can integrate arbitrary commands in the processing queue.

Comment: Oops! I noticed just now that is the icon "export to file" (with the green Arrow). This function allow me to export the uml in image and other format.